# Converting lazy loaded module into an eagerly loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I would like to convert one of my lazy loading modules into eagerly loading module. I have this code in my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const accountModule = () => import('./account/account.module').then(x => x.AccountModule);
const adminModule = () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(x => x.AdminModule);
const profileModule = () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(x => x.ProfileModule);
const scheduleModule = () => import('./schedule/schedule-routing.module').then(x => x.ScheduleRoutingModule);


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: profileModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: [Role.Admin] } },
    { path: 'schedule', loadChildren: scheduleModule },
    { path: 'report', component: RaportForDateComponent },
    { path: 'floating', component: FloatingSchedulesComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

I would like to convert `account` into eagerly loading module. This is my `account-routing.module` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'verify-email', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
            { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
            { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountRoutingModule { }
```

What do I need to change in my `app-routing.module.ts` `Routes` for `app-routing.module.ts` module to be eagerly loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `AccountModule` directly in

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AccountModule, AppRoutingModule],
  ...
```

and update root path in `AccountRoutingModule`.

**account-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'account', component: LayoutComponent,
           ^^^^^^^^
    children: [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

And finally, of course, don't forget to remove lazy part in

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done changes according to your description. The application seems to be hanging. I am working on where it is hanging.

Comment: I think routing is not working. I get white screen.

Comment: Sorry . Its working OK

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
const accountModule = () => import('./account/account.module').then(x => x.AccountModule)
```

as

```
const accountModule = () => AccountModule
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make changes in your app.routing module. Your code should look like this:

```
import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module';

const accountModule = () => AccountModule;
const adminModule = () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(x => x.AdminModule);
const profileModule = () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(x => x.ProfileModule);
const scheduleModule = () => import('./schedule/schedule-routing.module').then(x => x.ScheduleRoutingModule);

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: profileModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: [Role.Admin] } },
    { path: 'schedule', loadChildren: scheduleModule },
    { path: 'report', component: RaportForDateComponent },
    { path: 'floating', component: FloatingSchedulesComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: I have done the change. The `AccountModule` still loads lazily because it does not load at the start-up (I put some logging in constructors). After I log off the `AccountModule` is loaded.

Comment: you should import the module directly in the app.module.ts. Make sure it is at the end in import module.

Comment: imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AccountModule, 
  ],

Comment: Yep. It is loading now at the beginning.